# Exception breakPoint at [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]

Tags: ios, xcode

If I delete Exception BreakPoint ,all will be ok. But When I add Exception breakPoint to debug ,something wrong:

```
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  self.tabBarController = [[ALTabBarController alloc] init];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

[breakpoint like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNlzY.png)
 and run, project always break at [self.window makeKeyAndVisible] ,click "continue programe execution" button some times,it can be run

Comment: Can self.tabBarController be null?

Comment: What exception does it throw?

Comment: Project can run success when without breakPoint

Comment: Do you use some libraries like Realm? Sometimes libraries can throw exception in appDelegate but nothing is wrong.

Comment: @Niclou Don't use Realm

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472408/always-stop-in-app-delegate-after-enabling-all-exceptions-break-point

Comment: NiClou, It works!! Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit Exception breakpoint like this-

[image]

And select Objective C like this-

[image]

Hope this helps!