# Xcode 7: exception breakpoint firing in `main.m`, but app runs normally

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode7

I've set an "All Exceptions" exception breakpoint for my project. In Xcode 7, it mysteriously fires on launch in `main.m`, but there doesn't seem to be anything obviously wrong. On continuing, the app runs normally.

Even running the project in Xcode 6 now causes this breakpoint to fire.

[image: screenshot of breakpoint]

I can't figure out what is causing this. The threads don't indicate anything specific to what the cause is.

Maybe it's some sort of font issue in the Storyboard or something? Does anyone know a fix?

**NOTE:** It's a C++ exception, not Objective-C. Perhaps due to missing fonts. [Xcode throws an exception in Main() in iOS 8 with 'all exceptions' breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127004/xcode-throws-an-exception-in-main-in-ios-8-with-all-exceptions-breakpoint)

Comment: Maybe you've set a breakpoints for 'All exceptions'? Check the breakpoints tab

Comment: Yes, but like I said... it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Your terminology is incorrect; it's not a breakpoint (which is something *you* add during debugging), but rather a crash.  Have you enabled a breakpoint as per the accepted answer in the question you linked?

Comment: It doesn't actually "crash" at that point if the breakpoints aren't enabled. I have a breakpoint set on All Exceptions so that I can debug crashes. Yet, if I disable the breakpoint, it doesn't break there. So the point at which it breaks is a "phantom".

Comment: Did you add accidentally that breakpoint there? Did you try to remove it?

Comment: It's the default breakpoint for all exceptions.

Comment: I reworded the question, to make clear that the firing of the breakpoint is mysterious, the _presence_ of the breakpoint is not.

Comment: I figured the same issue, all exceptions breakpoint stops in main.m after application started. When disabled, app starts normaly.
Changing breakpoint type to objective-C only fixed this.

Comment: +1, I ran into this same issue when creating a dictionary of text attributes in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: I've got the same behaviour as @ToddAnderson - NSDictionary during launch was the culprit.

Comment: It may be firing because the previous instance you were debugging was killed by Xcode when you started the new instance.  Does it happen on the first launch of the app (just after you start Xcode) or only on subsequent launches?

Answer (score 26):

I have almost the identical problem in Xcode 7, as of beta 3. This workaround solved it for me.

Because it's a C++ exception, you can change your "All Exceptions" breakpoint to catch only Objective-C exceptions. Having done this, I no longer hit the mystery break on startup, and because I'm not writing C++,  get 99% of the value of having the "All Exceptions" break point on.

Here's how:

1. Go to the breakpoints tab (View > Navigators > Show Breakpoint Navigator or ⌘7).
2. Right click on the `All Exceptions` breakpoint and "Edit Breakpoint..."

[image: edit breakpoint]

3. Change the Exceptions covered to `Objective-C` only.

[image]

Comment: where have been all my life √

Answer (score 0):

I started seeing the same behaviour in my application using the shorthand dictionary initialisation `@{ ...: ... }` in the `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function.

The problem was solved by replacing it with `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys` instead. I'm not sure if this was specific to my case or if the compiler has some kind of a problem with the shorthand syntax, but it's worth checking out if you're using that syntax.