# Always trigger the all exceptions break point

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exception, lldb

I had enable a `All Exceptions` break point in my project.

But the UIApplicationMain() function always trigger the break point when the app launching.
I think there was no exceptions here because if I click the Next Button twice, the app will launch successfully.

I have tried commenting the code in the AppDelegate, but it does't work.

Comment: your app launch doesn't means there isn't any exception, it just means there isn't any unhandled exception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127004/xcode-throws-an-exception-in-main-in-ios-8-with-all-exceptions-breakpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions for it could be:

- Added custom font can cause this issue so, apparently delete (replace) it, somewhere in project is still his reference which causes C++ exception.

So, Delete or Replace all references to those fonts, Clean the project and check.

- Change from All Exceptions to Objective-C Exceptions in All Exceptions.

Check this answers will help more:

[Xcode throws an exception in Main() in iOS 8 with 'all exceptions' breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127004/xcode-throws-an-exception-in-main-in-ios-8-with-all-exceptions-breakpoint)

[Always stop in App delegate after enabling All exceptions break point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472408/always-stop-in-app-delegate-after-enabling-all-exceptions-break-point)

Try and check if it help:)