# Always stop in App delegate after enabling All C++ exceptions break point

Tags: ios, xcode

I am always getting stuck in App Delegate class when enabling "**All C++ exceptions**" & "**All exceptions**". I tried with enabling "**All Objective-C exceptions**", it's working fine.

I am not getting any message in (lldb) pane.

Getting stuck here:

[image]

With exception enable:

[image]

I have followed below links:

[Always stop in App delegate after enabling All exceptions break point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472408/always-stop-in-app-delegate-after-enabling-all-exceptions-break-point)

[Xcode throws an exception in Main() in iOS 8 with 'all exceptions' breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26127004/xcode-throws-an-exception-in-main-in-ios-8-with-all-exceptions-breakpoint)

[Always trigger the all exceptions break point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340355/always-trigger-the-all-exceptions-break-point)

As per the above link, I am not using any external font in my project.

Could you please help me why the app is always stuck in App Delegate?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this causing a specific problem for you, or are you just curious as to what's causing it? It shouldn't be a concern in most cases and doesn't mean there's necessary any problem with your app.

Comment: Enable zombie object and check any log prints or not

Comment: Hi karthikeyan, When I enable zombies then I got message "objc[62498]: Class _NSZombie_FBSXPCMessage is implemented in both ?? (0x60000327e640) and ?? (0x600003225050). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[62498]: Class _NSZombie_OS_xpc_int64 is implemented in both ?? (0x600003225080) and ?? (0x60000327e6a0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined." But I am not able to understand where I can fix it? Could you please help me?